# Apex Oracle custom login script

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I would like to know how to use another table for authenticating.
As you can see I've got a table named 'vdv_medewerker', this table contains two columns, -gebruikersnaam- & -wachtwoord-. These fields are being validated on login, and it works.

Now what I would like to do is, I would like this authenticating script to use values from another table named 'vdv_klant', this table also includes a -gebruikersnaam- & -wachtwoord- column.

I've tried finding a solution online, but I didn't succeed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    custom_inlog(p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
    v_gebruikersnaam varchar2(30);
    v_wachtwoord varchar2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord
    INTO v_gebruikersnaam, v_wachtwoord
    FROM vdv_medewerker
    WHERE UPPER(gebruikersnaam) = UPPER(p_username)
    AND wachtwoord = p_password;

    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   RETURN FALSE;
END;​
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably your APEX authentication scheme has been set up to call your function above?  So you can either just change your function to look at the new table, or you can create a new function based on the new table and change the APEX authentication scheme to call that instead of the old one:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I want one authetication script using two tables to login with. What you're seeing now is a custom script made for a n authentication scheme.

Comment: Ok so just write whatever SQL you want inside that function.

Comment: That's my point, I don't know how to write a script wich allows me to use two tables instead of one for authenticating.

Comment: @Jeremy, you're no clearer now than you were with the earlier question you asked (which seems to have been deleted now). What do you mean by "use two tables instead of one"?

Comment: @Jeremy, you need to explain how these 2 tables should be used - does the user have to be in both, or just in one or the other, or...?  Anyway what you need to do is quite simple: the function should do whatever it needs to to determine whether the username and password are good, and return TRUE if they are, FALSE if they are not.

Comment: I've got two tables: 'vdv_medewerker' & 'vdv_klant', they both have a column named 'gebruikersnaam' & 'wachtwoord'. These columns are used to identify the user trying to login, (username, password).

At the moment I'm trying to login, the script needs to identify a user from EITHER one of those tables. And I didn't know how to create a query that would do so.

But I've found an answer, I used an UNION. This allowed me to create a select query for both tables to identify the one trying to login.

Answer (score 1):

To give an answer after reading the comments you gave in the meantime, here is a working version for your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    custom_inlog(p_username IN VARCHAR2, p_password IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
    v_gebruikersnaam varchar2(30);
    v_wachtwoord varchar2(30);
BEGIN
    SELECT gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord
    INTO v_gebruikersnaam, v_wachtwoord
    FROM (
    SELECT gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM vdv_medewerker
    UNION
    SELECT gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord FROM vdv_klant
    )
    WHERE UPPER(gebruikersnaam) = UPPER(p_username)
    AND wachtwoord = p_password;
RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   RETURN FALSE;
END;​
```

But in the longrun i would suggest using a predfined view and imrpove your database structure in the future.